# Como Pegar um Id auto increment e uni-lo a uma Variável no mesmo insert

Tags: php, mysql

Como Pegar um Id auto increment recém criado e repeti-lo em outra coluna unindo-o a uma variável?

```
 Ex: Na hora do Insert pego idxxxx  repito somando a $varxxxx


  date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
  while (strtotime($start) <= strtotime($data_fim)) { // pega a data de inicio e a   
  data fim e faz o loop inserindo no mysql

  $sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO agenda_saidas(nome,url)
  VALUES('nome','agendados_ver.php?id=$varxxxxxx')",
  $conexao) or die( mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Até onde eu sei, isso não é possível. Você precisa primeiro fazer o `INSERT`, e depois um `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE agenda_saidas
SET url = CONCAT(url, id)
WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```